# Python: Why copying a Dask slice to Numpy array result in row count mismatch

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I am having error while copying a slice of dask array to nparray, the number of row doesn't match

```
store = h5py.File(s_file_path + '.hdf5', 'r')
dset = store['data_matrix']
data_matrix = da.from_array(dset, chunks=dset.chunks)
test_set = data_matrix[482:, :]
np_test_set = np.array(test_set, order='FORTRAN')

print "source_set shape: ", data_matrix.shape
print "test_set shape: ", test_set.shape
print "np_test_set shape: ", np_test_set.shape
```

results:

```
source_set shape:  (656, 473034)
test set shape:  (174, 473034)
np_test_set shape:  (195, 473034)
```

I am not very familiar with dask, I am using it because my data don't hold in RAM, is the row difference related to caching or the chunk size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the chunk to (10, 500) and now it seems to work :

```
data_matrix = da.from_array(dset, chunks=(10,500))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Typical ways to convert to numpy array

You can convert a dask.array to a numpy array by calling the `.compute` method

```
np_test_set = test_set.compute()
```

or by calling `np.asarray`

```
np_test_set = np.asarray(test_set)
```

#### Fortran ordering

In principle what you're doing now should work fine as well and so this may be a bug.  The only part of this that seems atypical is specifying the Fortran order ahead of time.  It would be interesting to see if changing this affects the result.

#### Additional information

If this is a genuine bug (as it appears it may be) then it would be good to [raise an issue](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/new).  It would be useful to also see the `chunks` of the dask.array.

Comment: I was using the Fortran ordering as requirement for scikit ML function, I just reproduce my problem with both. np_test_set = test_set.compute() and np_test_set = np.asarray(test_set), the chunks are little strange I can't display all in this windows, it is like ((65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 6),(47, 47, 47, (many) , 47, 47, 47, 47, 26))  Thank for your help and happy christmas

Comment: I recommend raising an issue.  If you can supply a reproducible example that will make it easier to track down what's going on.